# Windows console Socket Client Application UNICODE Format - connect function getting failed as shown in below code

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, mfc, c++14

`connect()` function is always getting failed. Any help would be appreciated

```
sockaddr_in addr;
SOCKET sock, client;

addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = 1818;
const char *svrIP = "127.0.0.1";
//addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", (PVOID *)(&addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr));
if (iResult)
{
    printf("WSA startup failed");
    return 0;
}


sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("Invalid socket");
    return 0;
}

iResult = connect(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
```

Comment: solved this issue by changing addr.sin_port = htons(serverPort);

Comment: Hey, OP. Welcome to Stack Overflow! A tip: you might get more traffic to your next question if you add the c++ tag in addition to the c++11 or c++14 tags.